# Insert a string (conditionally) in url using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to achieve this kind of mod_rewrite:

*if request_uri is not abc or def* change client side url from

```
domain.com/request_uri
```

to server side url

```
domain.com/xyz/request_uri
```

Essentially what I want is to insert a string to a url without users knowledge if s/he isn't trying to access certain predefined urls.

So far I have

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc$
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ xyz/$1 [L]
```

but this seems to get stuck in a loop (/xyz//xyz//xyz...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a condition to check for the component you're adding. You can use an additional `RewriteCond` or extend the regex. Try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(xyz(/.*)|abc|def)/?$
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ xyz/$1 [L]
```